# Unable to find V3.5 in IIS5.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-5

I am doing sample application on `MVC` when i run the application i am getting the following error

[image]

Also in my IIS i am unable to find the version 3.5 even i am having `2008` installed on my pc so can any one tell how to rectify this problems

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might need to configure [extensionless mappings](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) as IIS 5 doesn't support it.

Comment: EVen i follow that steps issue remains same

Comment: @User, it is normal that IIS doesn't show v3.5 of the framework. IIS shows only CLR versions and there is only 2.0 and 4.0 versions. .NET 3.5 uses CLR 2.0, so that's what you should pick. Try using extensions with your routes and registering this extension with IIS as shown in the guide if extensionless urls doesn't work for you (normally they should if you map the aspnet_isapi filter to all requests).

Comment: Even i follow the process as per the guided one the issue remains same